# Foreach with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which provides the <strike>profit</strike> results of my rows depending on what `Resultat_ID` is set to.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Indsats, Odds, Resultat_ID, Kamp FROM spil'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo " Gevinster: "; 
$Indsats = $row['Indsats'];
$Odds = str_replace(",", ".", $row['Odds']);
$sum = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    $Indsats = $row['Indsats'];
    $Odds = str_replace(",", ".", $row['Odds']);
    if ($row['Resultat_ID'] == 1)      //Win
    {
       $sum += $Indsats * ($Odds-1);
    }
    elseif ($row['Resultat_ID'] == 2)  //Loss
    {
       $sum += $Indsats * -1;
    }
    elseif ($row['Resultat_ID'] == 3)  //HalfWin
    {
       $sum += $Indsats * ($Odds-1) * 0.5;
    }
    elseif ($row['Resultat_ID'] == 4)  //HalfLoose
    {
       $sum += $Indsats * -0.5;
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

I also have a column called `Tipper_ID` which contains a number for each tipper and a table that contains `Tipper_ID` and `Tipper_Name`.

Besides the total <strike>profit</strike> results above, I want to get the <strike>profit</strike> results for each tipper, so basically run the above section for "all" and for each `Tipper_Name` in the Tipper-table and get the <strike>profit</strike> results for each part.

How do I do that ?

Danish/English [Translations](http://translate.google.com/):

```
Gevinster = Gains<br>
Indsats = Effort<br>
Odds = Odds<br>
Resultat = Results<br>
Kamp = Match/Game<br>
Spil = Games<br>
Tipper = Tips
```

Comment: Just a side-note: it's not recommanded to use mysql_* functions. Consider using PDO or mysqli if possible.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "profit" of your rows?

Comment: Is there a reason you use mysql_fetch_array()? It's returning (by default) both numeric and associative array elements. You probably want to use mysql_fetch_assoc() again. Do note the previous warnings about switching to mysqli_*.

Comment: Do you mean to essentially discard the first row of results? It's not within the loop and merely initializes $sum to 0. Note that there's no guarantee on the order of rows that will be returned from a query, unless you've done some sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Inside your while, perform another query for each result (depending on the number of results, performance can be not that good)
2. Create a VIEW with the results grouped by `Tipper_Name` (or whatever you need) and change your query adding an INNER JOIN using the VIEW you just created. Even if this solution is a little bit more complex, it's faster!

Answer (score 0):

This actually looks like a classic SQL problem:

```
SELECT   t.TIPPER_ID, t.TIPPER_NAME, 
         SUM(CASE(s.Resultat_ID WHEN 1 THEN Indsats*(Odds-1) ELSE 0 END)) AS Win,
         SUM(CASE(s.Resultat_ID WHEN 2 THEN Indsats*(-1) ELSE 0 END)) AS Loss,
         SUM(CASE(s.Resultat_ID WHEN 3 THEN Indsats*(Odds-1)*(0.5) ELSE 0 END)) AS HalfWin,
         SUM(CASE(s.Resultat_ID WHEN 4 THEN Indsats*(-0.5) ELSE 0 END)) AS HalfLoss

FROM         spil AS s 
LEFT JOIN    TIPPERS AS t ON t.TIPPER_ID=s.TIPPER_ID

GROUP BY     s.TIPPER_ID
```

For the total you should simply add those in the php.

Comment: I kind of understand what you have written, but due to lack of program skills, I can not figure out where I should put it in the code to get the result. Is it replacing my current SQL-query or how do I use it ?

Comment: This query should replace the current query and the "if" statements.
the `$row` parameter in the code after running this query and fetch the results with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will contain the following counters to each unique tipper `'TIPPER_ID','TIPPER_NAME','Win','Loss','HalfWin','HalfLoss'`.
If you want to get also the tipper total actions you could simply do: `$tipper_total=$row['Win']+$row['Loss']+$row['HalfWin']+$row['HalfLoss'];`